# How do I verify that a specific public key file is used with git?

Tags: git, ssh

I sent a 3rd party my public SSH key, which they used to add access for me to a particular repository. However, when I try to git clone, I get errors (in fact, I'm asked for a password).

I've run into issues before when what I thought was my public key, wasn't in fact the public key used by my git client. My question:

How do I verify which SSH key my git client uses?

```
>ssh git@git.wpengine.com info
git@git.wpengine.com's password:     <--- this shouldn't happen
```

Comment: Maybe this will help?: [Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey). It has information on how Git uses SSH keys.

Comment: Also, don't know if this helps, but it took about 10 minutes (per WPEngines' docs) for my key to be exchanged and then the prompt went away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an `~/.ssh/config` file in order to specify the exact hostname, user *and* private key you want to use:

```
Host wpengine 
user git
hostname git.wpengine.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myPrivateKey
```

That way, there is no ambiguity as to which key is used.

```
ssh -vvvT wpengine
```

That command will tell you what is happening.
Usually, the public key is incorrectly added to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in the server side.